# Mongoose: How to handle versioning?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Today I came to know about versioning concept in MongooseJS(here [Mongoose v3 part 1 :: Versioning](http://aaronheckmann.blogspot.in/2012/06/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning.html)). But I have question here, I like the versioning feature of Mongoose, but what should I do when my schema changes ?

For example, initially my schema looks like,

```
{
 "_id": String,
 "title": String,
 "description": String
}
```

Since I didn't know about versioning, i didn't add any versionKey option, just used the default versionKey, **__v**.

I created few documents with this above schema. Later I modified the schema as,

```
{
 "_id": String,
 "title": String,
 "description": String,

 "comments": Array
}
```

Here comes the problem, If I create any new document after this schema change I could able to add/push comments to the document.

But If I want to add/push comments to the document which were created with initial schema, I couldn't able to do, it throws **Versioning Error: No matching document found**.

Is there anyway to overcome this problem without disabling or skipping the versioning ?

Comment: Schema Migration will do the trick as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295357/how-to-properly-handle-mongoose-schema-migrations

Comment: then link of the initial thread is not available anymore